# Can we embed the thredded gem within the existing application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Currently i am using Thredded GEM for forums, I am not able to embed thredded in  the existing application. It currently opening in new window. Moreover i cant even change the css also, is there any way to do it ? Anybody please help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding embedding within the website, this is doable. You mount the engine in your main application and configure it to act as part of your application:
https://github.com/thredded/thredded/#application-layout

Theming. Yes there is a way to do it: https://github.com/thredded/thredded/#styles